# Unable to Mock call using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I am trying to mock KMSHttpClientImpl. But it is going to actual implementation of invokePOSTRequest method. Why my mocking is not working?

I have this class:

```java
public class KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl implements KMSAdminOrgOperations {
    /**
     * KMS HTTP wrapper to http client.
     */
    private static KMSHttpClientImpl kmsHttpClient;

    /**
     * KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl instance.
     */
    private static KMSAdminOrgOperations kmsAdminOrgOperationsInstance;

    /**
     * Private KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl Constructor.
     *
     */
    private KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl() {}

    /**
     * Method to get singleton instance of KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl class.
     * @param properties
     * @return KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl instance.
     * @throws KMSClientException
     */
    public static KMSAdminOrgOperations getInstance(final Properties properties)
    throws KMSClientException {
        synchronized(KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl.class) {
            if (kmsAdminOrgOperationsInstance == null) {
                kmsHttpClient = KMSHttpClientImpl.getKMSHttpClientInstance(properties);
                kmsAdminOrgOperationsInstance = new KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl();
            }
        }
        return kmsAdminOrgOperationsInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public OrganizationResponse createOrganization(final String serviceId,
        final String appId, final String orgId)
    throws KMSClientException {
        final OrganizationRequest organizationRequest =
            OrganizationRequest.builder().id(orgId).build();
        final String url = String.format(ORGANIZATION_ENDPOINT, serviceId, appId);
        return kmsHttpClient.invokePOSTRequest(url, organizationRequest,
            OrganizationResponse.class);
    }
}
```

This is my test class:

```java
  public class KMSAdminOrgOperationsImplTest {
      /**
       * KMS Admin Org Operations
       */
      @InjectMocks
      private KMSAdminOrgOperationsImpl kmsAdminOrgOperations;

      /**
       * Mocked KMSHttpClientImpl instance
       */
      @Mock
      private KMSHttpClientImpl kmsHttpClient;


      /**
       *
       */
      @Before
      public void setUp() {
          initMocks(this);
      }


      /**
       * Method to test createOrganization.
       *
       * @throws KMSClientException if there is a problem
       */
      @Test
      public void testCreateOrganization() throws KMSClientException {
          Mockito.when(kmsHttpClient.invokePOSTRequest(Mockito.anyString(),
              Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getOrganizationResponse());
          // TODO PS-6352 This needs to be changed after adding implementation
          final OrganizationResponse response = kmsAdminOrgOperations
              .createOrganization(SERVICE_ID, APP_ID, ORG_ID);
          assertEquals("OrgId should match", ORG_ID, response.getId());
      }
  }
```

I am trying to mock **KMSHttpClientImpl** using Mockito. But when I am trying to execute my testcases it is going to actual implementation of invokePOSTRequest method. Is there anything I am doing wrong. Why my mocking is not working?

Comment: When using mockito for static stuff, make sure you understand how it works, and what you need for it, see https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/ for example. BUT: consider mocking static things bad practice. Most of the time, a non-static design can be tested much easier.

Comment: Are you using a dependency injection framework, like Spring? Your code doesn't look like it, but `@InjectMocks` is geared towards that, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple observations:

1. First of all private static KMSHttpClientImpl kmsHttpClient; is not being used anywhere in code.
2. KMSHttpClientImpl.getKMSHttpClientInstance(properties) is cant be mocked directly as getKMSHttpClientInstance is static method, maybe you need to try Power Mockito
3. Use @Spy along with @InjectMock. @Spy will provide you the flexibility of partially mock in an easy way.

Comment: You shouldn't advise using `@Spy` as a general rule; ["real spies should be used carefully and occasionally, for example when dealing with legacy code."](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13). Mocks should be used whenever possible.

Comment: A) mockito does support static method mocking since lately https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/ ... but B) it might still be the wrong approach. Static code is just harder to test, and typically, when people say "try PowerMock", what they should say is "you have untestable code, redesign it to be easy to test"

Comment: @daniu And mocking static methods using PowerMock(ito) (or even Mockito these days) isnt exactly best practice either ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat is there a way to do this with Mockito instead of powerMockito?

Comment: @priyanka Maybe, that is why I posted that link to the mockito blog twice. I havent used mockito for static mocking so far, and honestly: I dont think I ever want to. So: step back, research the documentation, and start with small test examples, and see how far you get.